# ReBus equivalent to NServiceBus Saga ReplyToOriginator

Tags: c#, publish-subscribe, saga, rebus

I am working with Sagas in ReBus and from my experience with NServiceBus you could reply to the original creator of the Saga to give updates, something like this:

```
 Saga<>.ReplyToOriginator
```

I do not see an equivalent way of doing this with ReBus. Is there a way to do this, and if not what is a good pattern (other than the originator polling) I can use that will achieve the same thing? An example is trying to create a customer and the client wanting to know when it is created before trying to change it's address.

Here is a trivial example of the Customer scenario I quickly put together:

```
public class CreateCustomerSaga : Saga<CreateCustomerData>,
    IAmInitiatedBy<CreateCustomerCommand>,
    IHandleMessages<CustomerUniqunessCheckResult>
{
    private readonly IBus _bus;
    private readonly ICustomerResourceAccess _customerResourceAccess;

    public CreateCustomerSaga(IBus bus, ICustomerResourceAccess customerResourceAccess)
    {
        _bus = bus;
        _customerResourceAccess = customerResourceAccess;
    }

    public override void ConfigureHowToFindSaga()
    {
        Incoming<CustomerUniqunessCheckResult>(x => x.IsCustomerUnique).CorrelatesWith(y => y.CustomerId);
    }

    public void Handle(CreateCustomerCommand message)
    {
        Data.CustomerId = message.CustomerId;
        Data.CustomerName = message.CustomerName;

        _bus.Send(new CheckCustomerUniquenessCommand(message.CustomerId));
    }

    public void Handle(CustomerUniqunessCheckResult message)
    {
        if (message.IsCustomerUnique)
        {
            _customerResourceAccess.CreateCustomer(Data.CustomerId, Data.CustomerName);

            // This is what seems to be missing from ReBus to reply to the original sender
            _bus.?(new CustomerCreatedEvent(Data.CustomerId));
        }
        else
        {
            // This is what seems to be missing from ReBus to reply to the original sender
            _bus.?(new CustomerAlreadExistsEvent(Data.CustomerId));
        }
    }
}

public class CustomerCreatedEvent
{
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    public CustomerCreatedEvent(Guid customerId)
    {
        CustomerId = customerId;
    }
}

public class CustomerAlreadExistsEvent
{
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    public CustomerAlreadExistsEvent(Guid customerId)
    {
        CustomerId = customerId;
    }
}

public class CustomerUniqunessCheckResult
{
    public bool IsCustomerUnique { get; set; }
}

public class CheckCustomerUniquenessCommand
{
    public CheckCustomerUniquenessCommand(Guid customerId)
    { }
}

public interface ICustomerResourceAccess
{
    void CreateCustomer(Guid customerId, string customerName);
}

public class CreateCustomerCommand
{
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}

public class CreateCustomerData : ISagaData
{
    public CreateCustomerData()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public int Revision { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other code? Could you give a brief overview on technology you are describing? Involved in programming for the past 18 years, I have no clue of what you are talking about. If it's something new, would be nice if you could relate it to existing technologies, that are currently available.

Comment: I added an example, for technology see the tags (ReBus, C#)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately there's no *reply to originator* function in Rebus' sagas at the moment. You can easily do it though, by storing the originator's endpoint when your saga is created like this (in all `Handle` methods of messages that can initiate the saga):

```
if (IsNew) {
    Data.Originator = MessageContext.GetCurrent().ReturnAddress;
}
```

and then when you want to reply back to the originator:

```
bus.Advanced.Routing.Send(Data.Originator, new HelloThereMyFriend());
```

I've often thought about adding this to Rebus though, either as an extra field on `ISagaData`, or as an extra interface `ISagaDataWithOriginator` that you could optionally apply to your saga data, but I've never had the need (enough) myself.

Answer (score 1):

If each sender is a separate (virtual) machine, like in my implementation, you could get a guaranteed reply to originator by using their machine unique ID or MAC address in the reply queue name, like this:

```cs
Bus = Configure.With(adapter)
               .Transport(t => t.UseSqlServer(DbConfiguration.DatabaseConnectionString,
                                              sInstanceId, sInstanceId + ".Error")
               .EnsureTableIsCreated())
               ...
```

If each originator has a unique queue ID, the consumer can reply to originator simply by using Bus.Reply.

The unique machine id can be determined using System.Management:

```cs
string uuid = string.Empty;

ManagementClass mc = new System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_ComputerSystemProduct");
if (mc != null)
{
  ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
  if (moc != null)
  {
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
    {
      PropertyData pd = mo.Properties["UUID"];
      if (pd != null)
      {
        uuid = (string)pd.Value;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or by using the MAC address of the machine (our fallback code):

```cs
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uuid))
{
  uuid = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
  .Where(ni => ni.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
  .FirstOrDefault()
  .GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
}
```